# Why can't I access property when using switchMap?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, switchmap

I have a method attached to a button. A user enters their name in an input, and when the button is clicked, information from that user is displayed. How I am planning to do that is explained below..

I am trying to pass in a value from one Observable into another Observable. The value I am trying to get from the first Observable is an ID that is then used within the second Observable.

My current method of doing this is using the switchMap operator. However, when passing in the ID from the first Observable into the second, I am seeing 'undefined' in my console..

I am thinking that either I am not accessing the ID correctly when calling the first Observable.. Or I should not use switchMap ??

It's also weird and I thought I was close because using Object.keys(player)['0'] I can get the first Object key (Data). But using Object.keys(player)['0'].id;  is undefined :/

This is response object I am trying to get the ID from:

[image: Imgur]

click function within my component:

```
click() {
  this.playerService.getPlayer(this.searchString).pipe(
      switchMap(player => {
        let ID = Object.keys(player)['0'];
        let anotherID = ID['0'].id;

        return this.playerService.getSeasonStats(anotherID);
      }))
    .subscribe(id => this.player = id)
}
```

Service with getPlayer method and getSeasonStats method:

```
getPlayer(query: string):Observable<Player> {
  let getHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer API_Key', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'}); 
  return this.http.get<Player>(`https://api.com/shards/steam/players?filter[playerNames]=${query}`, {
    observe:'body',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: getHeaders
  });
}


getSeasonStats(id: string):Observable<SeasonStats[]> {
  let getHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Authorization':'Bearer API_Key', 'Accept': 'application/vnd.api+json'}); 
  return this.http.get<SeasonStats[]>(`https://api.com/shards/steam/players/${id}/seasons/division.bro.official.pc-2018-04`,  {
    observe:'body',
    responseType: 'json',
    headers: getHeaders
  });
}
```

Comment: Just to clarify, the `player` argument in `switchMap` is undefined?  Or `ID`?

Comment: Passing in (anotherID) into getSeasonStats becomes undefined. ID['0'] returns 'Data' Key the same way the variable ID returns Data. I was getting Typescript errors when trying to use ID = Object.keys(player['0']) so I created the variable anotherID so I could use ['0'].id

Comment: argh I'm sorry for the confusingly long explanation to your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is:

```
let ID = Object.keys(player)['0'];
let anotherID = ID['0'].id;
```

the line `Object.keys(player)['0']` returns you `"data"` as string, now doing `['0']` you get "d"... so your result is `"d".id => undefined`

Maybe you need to do something like:

```
let playerData = player["data"][0];
let anotherID = playerData.id;
```

Comment: ooo, I will try this when I get home. Thank you :)